# Don't want div below post title to show in excerpt

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to have a div setup directly underneath the post title which floats to the left and contains an adsense 300x250 block, and then the post content wraps around it on the right. All of this works fine when viewing the individual post... but when I go to the main page of my blog where it shows all of the post excerpts, it displays the div in there which I don't want.

I've tried correcting this using CSS and just trying to target the div on the main page specifically and setting it to display none (i.e. .post_content.myAd{display:none;...}), and then having it visible by targeting the specific one (i.e. .single.myAd{display:inline;...} since my ad div 'myAd' is located within .post_content on the main page, but within .single on the individual blog post).

This my full css:

```
.single.aboveVideoAd{
position: relative;
display:inline;
float: left;
width: 300px;  
height: 250px; 
margin-right: 15px; 
margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.post_content.aboveVideoAd{
display:none;
}
```

As requested, here is my html of the loop for index.php (which displays the excerpts) and single.php for the single post:

index.php: http://pastebin.com/62gQfh2h

single.php: http://pastebin.com/x18G56CA

Any ideas? I've seen tons of sites that have ad blocks under the post and don't have this issue, so I feel like there should be a more simple fix for it other than having to mess around with the css.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe provide some of your html as well, we need to know if you're targeting the right div with your css

Comment: The CSS approach should work but as atnatn says we can't really tell you why it doesn't if we don't have the HTML. I posted a PHP alternative since you didn't seem to like the CSS solution.

Comment: I've posted the html of the loop for single.php and index.php, please let me know if any other info is needed. I'm not opposed to the CSS solution, just can't seem to get it to work and also just thought that there might be an even easier solution since it seems like it would be a common occurrence for blogs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will strip tags and their contents from a text: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#86964

To make things easier, I will reproduce it:

```
<?php 
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 
    
  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
    if($invert == FALSE) { 
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
    else { 
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
  } 
  elseif($invert == FALSE) { 
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
  } 
  return $text; 
} 
?>
```

This could be bound to get_excerpt,

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', function( $content ) {
    return strip_tags_content( $content, '<div>', TRUE );
});
```

I have not tested this code.